# How does function evaluation work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
  function noisy(f) {
    return function(arg) {
       console.log("calling with", arg);
       var val = f(arg);
       console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
       return val;
    };
  }
  noisy(Boolean)(0);
```

Can someone clear my doubts by answering the below questions:

1. Why the function is called like this: noisy(Boolean)(0);
2. what is the "val" variable purpose and how it works.
3. to which function the value of "val" is returned.

Kindly help me to clear my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why the function is called like this: noisy(Boolean)(0);**

Since the function `noisy` returns a seperate function, you can call it with two sets of parantheisis. The first, '`Boolean`', is passed straight to noisy. After noisy executes and the anonymous function is returned, '0' is passed to that function.

**2. what is the "val" variable purpose and how it works.**

For `val` to work as intended, the first argument should also be a function. In this case, 'Boolean' works as it is the name of a javascript object which can be constructed.

**3. to which function the value of "val" is returned.**

It is not returned to any function. Rather, the result can be stored in a variable like

`var result = noisy(Boolean)(0);`

Answer (score 0):

The code `noisy(Boolean)` is calling the function `noisy` passing in `Boolean` as `f`.  That function is then *returning another function* which does not have a name (this is known as an ["anonymous function"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions)).

The line `noisy(Boolean)(0)` is then calling that anonymous function, passing in the value `0` which is known inside that function as `arg`.  That function executes the line `var val = f(arg);` which, if you follow the parameters passed in, is essentially doing `var val = Boolean(0)`.

You could simplify this by doing something like this:

```
var firstResult = noisy(Boolean);
var result = firstResult(0);
```

where `result` is the `val` returned by the anonymous function.  In this example, its the same as calling `Boolean(0)` which is `false`, so `result` will be `false`.

You could also try:

```
var firstResult = noisy(String);
var result = firstResult(21);
```

where `result` (again, the `val` returned by the anonymous function) would be `"21"`.  In this example, its the same as calling `String(21)` which is `"21"` (a string, not a number).

Answer (score 0):

Consider it in parts:

```
noisy(Boolean)
```

calls *noisy* and passes it the built–in Boolean object, which is a function that is the constructor of all Boolean objects.

The *noisy* function:

```
function noisy(f) {
    return function(arg) {
       console.log("calling with", arg);
       var val = f(arg);
       console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
       return val;
    };
  }
```

returns a function that has a closure to *f*, which is a reference to *Boolean*. Functions have closures to all the variables of their outer execution contexts.

When this function is called:

```
...(0);
```

passes the value *0*:

```
    ... function(arg) {
```

which is assigned to *arg*:

```
       console.log("calling with", arg);
```

logs "calling with 0"

```
       var val = f(arg);
```

Assigns the result of `Boolean(0)` to *val*. When *Boolean* is called as a function, it performs type conversion. *0* converts to *false*, so that is the value that is assigned to *val*.

```
       console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
```

Logs "called with 0 - got false"

```
       return val;
```

Returns the value of *val* (i.e. `false`), but nothing is done with it so it vanishes into the ether.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what function `noisy` does :

1. It accepts a function as an argument, here noisy is called with Boolean which is a function passed as a parameter to noisy.
2. It returns a function which returns the value of argument passed to the function which itself is an argument to noisy. To simplify, `noisy` is called with Boolean(0). `noisy` will return a function which returns the value of `Boolean` called with `0`

I hope this clears what this code snippet does. Now to answer your queries:

1. Why the function is called like this: noisy(Boolean)(0)?
   The function noisy is defined in such a way that it needs a function and a parameter to be passed to that function. So, `Boolean` is the function passed to `noisy` and `0` is the argument passed to `Boolean`
2. what is the "val" variable purpose and how it works.
   `val` is the value of Boolean(0)in this case.
3. value of `val` is returned to the function which is returned by `noisy`